# Make a countdown from timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

Is there any way to make a countdown with 60 seconds... Here is the code for timer:

```
var count = 0;
var timer = $.timer(function() {
    $('#counter').html(++count);
});
timer.set({ time : 1000, autostart : true });
```

What I need to chabge to make this code like countdown> THANKS

Comment: I new to jquery, sorry about trivial question

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Counts from 0 to 60.

```
var count = 0, timer = setInterval(function() {
    $("#counter").html((count++)+1);
    if(count == 59) clearInterval(timer);
}, 1000);
```

Or from 60 to 0:

```
var count = 60, timer = setInterval(function() {
    $("#counter").html(count--);
    if(count == 1) clearInterval(timer);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: @Eliot Wat should i make to to show an alert , if timer shows zero .. And when alert is closed it should redirect another page

Comment: @sankrish: You'd be better off starting a new question, if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = 60;
var timer = $.timer(function() {
    $('#counter').html(--count);
});
timer.set({ time : 1000, autostart : true });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var timer;
var count = 60;

$("#counter").text(count);
//update display

timer = setTimeout(update, 1000);
//this allows for 'clearTimeout' if needed

function update()
{
    if (count > 0)
    {
       $("#counter").text(--count);
       timer = setTimeout(update, 1000);
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Done!!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please tel me how can i display an alert if timer is 0 and also it should redirect to another page if timer expires